# How can I easily store my C# data structure(XML serialiazable) into a database?

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq, serialization

I have a C# data structure which consists of classes and collections which have references to each other. Currently I am using Serialization to store the structure in XML, which works as a handy way to save/load the structure into my application.

If I want to be able to save/load the structure into a database, is there a simple way? Should I use LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be 100% clear LINQ has nothing to do with storing data in a database. LINQ is a language query for c# with syntax that resembles SQL.

So in order to answer your question you could look at the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723.aspx) (I'd recommend this if you are using .NET 4.0) or [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)

Comment: Thank for that. I've just been reading about LINQ and realised the same (and realised that my question now looks really noobish!). I'll check out the Entity Framework..

Comment: The whole naming of LINQ and LINQ to *blah* is very confusing. Microsoft could have done better with their naming.

Answer (score 1):

It currently depends on your needs, and the db engine you are using:

- If you need to perform queries against the XML contents you can use a XML field ([mssql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and oracle do support them).
- If you only need to store/retrieve it, just store it in a long string field (NText in sqlserver. NCLob in Oracle).

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll read up about XML fields. I'll mark an answer once I've finished all this reading!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx)?

**EDIT**: I don't know if this would be ok for you, but if you can define DB tables to hold your data structures, you could have code auto-generated using LINQ to SQL. Check [ScottGu's tutorial on LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx). If your data structures are not changing too often this could be a good way to go.

Comment: Not yet. I'll take a look thanks. I was wondering if there was a built-in way of doing this - like the XML serializer - rather than using third party code?